# Setting Rails Credentials For Production Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, credentials

I am trying to store my stripe live key via Credentials as shown in the Securing Rails Application Guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#custom-credentials

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the keys are written to the credentials file and in the test and development environments they work but when pushing to production I get errors that say my API Keys are not set. Here are what my credentials file and production config look like:

```
Credentials file ->
stripe_live: xxx.xxx.xxx

config/environments/production: 
Stripe.api_key = Rails.application.credentials.stripe_live
```

I've also tried setting the keys with this command
`rails credentials:edit --environment production` and still no luck in the production environment.

How do I set rails credentials for the production environment? Do I need to set the RAILS_MASTER_KEY as an env variable in my production environemtn?

Answer (score 1):

Set RAILS_MASTER_KEY to the string located within config/master.key . Rails automatically will use this value to decrypt your credentials file. A separate credentials file is optional, but if you do chose to use the separate credentials file you need to be sure that you use that key for the RAILS_MASTER_KEY env variable.